# Объединить функции

Tags: javascript

Помогите плииз. долблюсь уже который час

Есть форма оплаты https://topinfa.ru/oplata.php

Когда вводишь поле суммы input text
И отмечаешь галочками людей снизу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

внизу автоматически идет подсчет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и когда я убираю или ставлю чекбоксы сумма меняется правильно +-100
но когда я меняю саму сумму 100 то должна автоматически измениться итоговая сумма но этого не происходит. помогите плииз.

вот код:

```
<script>
    $(':checkbox').on('change', function(){
        var value = $('#sum').val();
        var value1 = $(':checkbox:checked').length;
        $('#count').text(value1 * $('#sum').val() + ' ₽');
    });
</script>

<font color="red" size="5"><span id="count">
    
<span id="errmsg14"></span>
<script>
   $('#sum').keyup(function(){
      var Value =  $('#sum').val() + '₽';
      $('#errmsg14').empty();
      $('#errmsg14').text(Value);
   });
</script>
</span>
<button type=" button" class="submit" onclick="$('#donate').submit()">
  Внести пожертвование
</button>
```

Comment: Одна считает кол-во чекбосов активированных на странице

$(':checkbox').on('change', function(){
value1 = $(':checkbox:checked').length;
$('#count').text(value1);
});

Вторая функция возвращает значение поля input text

$('#sum').keyup(function(){
Value = $('#sum').val();
$('#errmsg14').empty();
$('#errmsg14').text(Value);
});

Мне нужно значение поля text умножить на кол-во чекбоксов отмеченных.
Но надо сделать так чтобы при нажатии на чекбокс или изменении поля input значение автоматически менялось.
То есть надо как то оба функции выполнить одновременно.

Comment: извините за оффтоп, но на скрине выбрано пожертвования для **2** людей (по **100** рублей), а сумма получается **300**. что ж Вы за люди такие, что на благотворительности такой бешеный процент себе берете? :D

Comment: это не процент. это как бы 3 человека. первый он в водит в поле сумма 100. и еще по сотке для двух других людей

Answer (score 0):

внутри Вашего слушателя `$('#sum').keyup` Вы не учитывали то, что измененная сумма должна умножаться в зависимости от выбранных пожертвований. рабочий вариант будет выглядеть так:

```
$('#sum').keyup(function(){
      var Value =  $('#sum').val() + '₽';
      $('#errmsg14').empty();
      var checkedItemsLength = $(':checkbox:checked').length; // количество выбранных чекбоксов
      $('#errmsg14').text(Value + checkedItemsLength * 100); // добавляем к новой сумме сумму количества выбранных чекбоксов
});
```